# How to go forward and back through an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array / object like below:

```
{
    “Food’ : [{‘ImagesId”: ”38”, ”ImagesPath”: ”url”, ”Tag”: ”Food”}],
    “Sport’: [{‘ImagesId”: ”64”, ”ImagesPath”: ”url”, ”Tag”: ”Sport”}]
}
```

I want to be able to display one image at a time and have buttons to go forward and back through the images. I need to have a variable that describes the currently viewed image.

Below is what I currently have and it allows me move forward through the array but not back. I just want a simple function that randomises the array above displays one image at a time and allowing the user to move forward and back through the images.

Finally I need something like window.currentlyShown

```
function receivedData(data) {
      function changeOfferPicture() {
           if (window.currentlyShownOffer) {
               var tagArray = data[window.currentlyShownOffer.Tag];
               tagArray.splice(tagArray.indexOf(currentlyShownOffer), 1);
               //alert(window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesId);
           }


           var tags = Object.keys(data);
           var randomTag = tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)];
           var tagArray = data[randomTag];
           window.currentlyShownOffer = tagArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * tagArray.length)];
           window.shownCache.push(window.currentlyShownOffer);
           document.getElementById('top5').src = window.currentlyShownOffer.ImagesPath;
      };
}
```

Comment: "Below is what I currently have I don't want it like this." You'll have to be more specific than that.